# How to search for any text in List<String>

Tags: c#

I have list and I need to search for items something like:

if the user searches for smi it will bring all items that include smi?

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the following example

```
string serachKeyword ="o";

List<string> states = new List<string>();
states.Add("Frederick");
states.Add("Germantown");
states.Add("Arlington");
states.Add("Burbank");
states.Add("Newton");
states.Add("Watertown");
states.Add("Pasadena");
states.Add("Maryland");
states.Add("Virginia");
states.Add("California");
states.Add("Nevada");
states.Add("Ohio");

List<string> searchResults = states.FindAll(s => s.Contains(serachKeyword));
```

Answer (score 6):

This will find all results that start with 'smi' (mySearchString)

```
foreach(var result in myList.Where(s => s.IndexOf(mySearchString) == 0))
{
 // Do whatever
}
```

This will find any that contains 'smi' (mySearchString)

```
foreach(var result in myList.Where(s => s.IndexOf(mySearchString,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1))
{
 // Do whatever
}
```

This will search for your text (ignoring case), and return any strings that contain the text.

that should work - Don't have IDE close by, but hope it helps

Comment: Maybe using RegEx for case-insensiteve search.

Comment: Yeah, but then you have two problems :) ha, nah don't have compiler handy so can't confirm the syntax.

Comment: Use BeginsWith() instead of IndexOf(), yeah?
And use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase to ignore case. Resort to a Regex if you need more flexibility (see my example).

Comment: StringCompararers won't work with Contains, it only accepts a string. Short of creating an extension method.

Comment: You can use this lambda to do case-insensitive search:

s => s.IndexOf("fs", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for the confusion. You can use StringComparers on IndexOf, though.

Answer (score 1):

To search items that Include 'smi'

```
var result = list.Where(s => s.Contains("smi"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab all of the items that contain "smi" anywhere, like "smith" and "vesmit":

```
var list = myList.Where(m => m.Contains("smi"));
```

If you want to grab all of the items that contain "smi" at the start of the string, like "smith", "smitten", and "smile":

```
var list = myList.Where(m => m.BeginsWith("smi"));
```

If you want more flexibility, you can use a Regex

```
var list = myList.Where(m => Regex.IsMatch(m, "regexPattern"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a version of C# without LINQ you can use the `Find` method of the `List` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) (it's got quite big sample on that page too).